# JPA annotation to do on-many mapping

Tags: jpa

I am facing an issue while doing one-many mapping,
for e.g. I have a class USER and another class PHONE and there is one to many mapping from USER to PHONE.
I have designed my class like this,

```
class USER{

@Column(name="user_id")
UUID user_id;

@OneToMany
Set<PHONE> phones;
}

class PHONE{
@Column(name="phone_id")
UUID phone_id;

@Column(name=user_id)
UUID user_id;
}
```

Is there any annotation I can use without defining type of USER in phone class ?

If I do like this "USER user in PHONE class" then I can define uni or bi directional relationship. but I want to keep user_id in PHONE Table because when I get a PHONE I dont want to get USER details also. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to load the user when loading a phone, make the association lazy:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Phone> phones;
}


@Entity
public class Phone
    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;
}
```

Note that the above code also respects the Java naming conventions. Classes should not be in all-uppercase.

Comment: but I have both of these tables in different schemas and other thing is that in JSON response I want to pass User id in some hyperlink format so that user can navigate to USer profile also.

Comment: If they're in different schemas, you can't have a OneToMany from user to phone either.